# A better UILabel sizeToFit()?

Tags: ios, uilabel, uifont, uistackview

I would like to center a `UILabel` based on its glyph dimensions.  When I use `sizeToFit()` on a label its vertical positioning in a layout is not glyph aligned -- the label appears to be lower than it should.  For example, when I have label with text "]" and plug that into a horizontal `UIStackView` the actual glyph of `]` is not vertically (y) centered with other elements in the stack.  I am looking for a Swift 3 iOS 10 solution.